# Out of memory on a 15095824-byte allocation in android ImageView

Tags: bitmap, imageview, base64, android-bitmap

I am trying to get the images in ListView ,in such way i will recieve the images in String .But if i am using low resolution image there is no problem but i have to get high resolution image i get **Out of memory on a 15095824-byte allocation**

Here is my android code:

```
  if(image[position]!=null) {
        byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(image[position].getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        assert hirerPicLocal != null;
        hirerPicLocal.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes,0, imageAsBytes.length));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image is too big! You need to scale it.

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize  = 2; // your "scale"
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length, options);
```

For more information see documentation: [Loading Large Bitmaps](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)